# reaching request limit in Parse

Tags: request, parse-platform, limit

Our game is using Parse to store player's score.
Current free Parse plan is 30 req/sec limit. Right now we have just 200 users and that's enough.

But this week we are going to make big marketing push and probably we will reach request limit.

What will happens after that?

Is requests will be dropped until we switch to paid plan?

Should we take care about that beforehand and switch to paid plan?

Comment: I believe the requests are just dropped until you are allowed more. So the user will have to keep "submitting" their scores until they are lucky enough to be one of the thirty within that second.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because stackoverflow.com is not the parse.com support staff.

Comment: yes not exactly question for this place, just note that limit is enforced by minute so rather than 30req/s it is 1800reqs/minute, which gives wider margin for clients and errors.

Comment: If you're hitting the limit on 200 users it seems you're sending request very often. It gives me some idea that MIGHT be useful. Example case - If you save score every time player kills some monster - consider saving it locally and saving it on parse once per 5 minutes or when user closes the game app it should reduce req/s A LOT. The only case I see when you MUST send every iteraction is multiplayer (players move / chat etc) - normally (single player) a lot of data can be saved locally and requested to be saved once a while.

Answer (score 3):

User request will be dropped if they are over and above 30 req/sec.

But I do not think that you should make the switch now.

Keep the track of your users requests and only upgrade the plan once you find that your request count are above free plan limit.