# What is the point of the Javascript client key?

Tags: javascript, security, parse-platform

[Part 1 of the Parse Security Series](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-i-are-you-the-key-master/) states

> The client key is given out to your users, so anything that can be done with just the client key is doable by the general public, even malicious hackers.

...so why does the client key exist?

I understand that a logged-in user will get special privileges, but if some site functionality is legitimately available to the general public, why is there a key at all?

Comment: Start reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

Answer (score 1):

I think "client key" is a legacy term from early parse.com.  A better name for it now would be something like "iOS and Android SDK identifier".  When it was once an iOS sdk/backend, the client key was kept in relative obscurity in compiled source.

This was undone by the addition of javascript. Speculating here, but parse probably wanted to allow existing developers with shipped apps to add JS without compromising security they had assumed with the original.  So parse provided a newly titled and distinct "javascript key".  Notice how many "keys" there are now ... more like client type identifiers than keys in any security sense of the term.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to withhold credentials from your users.  They have to connect to your application somehow.  The mere act of accessing the Parse Backend requires it.

So what do you do?

In my case, I don't give the Parse key out in the client app; rather I'm wrapping it inside of something like [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/), which means I can keep users from accessing the Parse backend directly.  Yes, that means my users will have an IAM role; but I can lock that down and revoke as needed (and use AWS's IAM API to do so).  I also have rate limiting abilities that would otherwise cause Parse [to just silently drop requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24888474/16587).

You also don't have to actually give clients the JavaScript key -- you could store it in your `Node.js` application and simply manage access control yourself.  Another layer of indirection always solves the issue.

Comment: It's worth noting that I'm actually doing this now.  Before this, I would have created my own middle-tier to handle this sort of thing; but since AWS just started offering the API gateway, I'm making use of it.

Comment: Parse's documentation doesn't suggest a need to hide the client key. I'd like to understand what their thinking is before I go custom like you did.

Comment: @adamdport it's really a platform agnostic reason that I talk about in my answer. If you want to know what they think, perhaps you should pose a question on their forum or ask them on Twitter?